# Resources.resx in c# projects

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem using a `Resources.resx` - `Resources.de.resx` - combination in a C#/WPF project.
The whole solutions contains several projects and some projects contains resource files.

When starting the main project I can switch the language successfully from English to German. But the GUI elements from the sub projects still show the English text.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different properies that you need to be concerned with: `Culture` and `UICulture`.

If you set the `Culture` property to `en-US`, then all the decimal places, time formatting, etc will be the way that it is in the US.

Setting the `UICulture` to `en-US` tells ASP.NET controls to render currencies, times, etc. as they are in the US.

So, either you've set one, and not the other......OR you need some code to recursively set them throughout your sub projects when a change is made.

Comment: There seems to be no ASP.NET involved, since he tagged his question with `WPF`.

Comment: That's right: it's a WPF application. The problem ist: the location switch works fine within the main project (presentation layer). The software elements of the application layer don't switch correctly. Any further ideas?